# Need Help Regarding Storing and then printing variable in c language

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I want to make a program which takes the input from the user in the form,
`__/__/____`.

What I made was

```
{
    int a, b, c,d,e,f;
    printf("Please Enter the *Joining Date* in the format DD/MM/YYYY\n");
    scanf_s("%d""%d""%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("The Date you entered was %d/%d/%d\n", a, b, c);
```

What it does is, after each input the cursor moves to the new line. Please Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Its very unclear what you want . But if you want to enter in a single line just press space after each numbers instead of number.

Comment: try something like : scanf("%d/%d/%d",&a,&b,&c);

Comment: `scanf_s("%02d/%02d/%04d", &a, &b, &c);`

Comment: I have one question, why `"%d""%d""%d"` instead of `"%d%d%d"`? And where are the `/`?

Comment: @ameyCU: https://ideone.com/68CJVU , using `scanf` instead of `scanf_s`

Comment: @AlterMann Well , good it worked .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is

```
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d",&d,&m,&y) == 3)
    your_input_is_valid();
else
    your_input_is_invalid();
```

this will ignore the `"/"` in the input.

in the printf some chars are skiped  like /  because there is `/n` `/t` and other
so to view DD/MM/YYYY
you should use :

```
DD//MM//YYYY
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much, I really appreciate it!!